# Array inaccessible from within for loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a userss array that I do not appear to be able to use in any type of loop.  the array "userss" is undefined when ever I try to access it in the loop.

Below is the generated javascript/html.  I am sure its something simple I've just been staring at this way too long and I cannot see the mistake.  I cannot access any property from within the loop including the ones I already used just above it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userss = [];
userss[ '1' ] = { id:'1', fname:'Lorem', lname: 'ipsum', uname: 'as', email: 'none@none.com', loca: '', flags: 'a', active: '1' };
userss[ '2' ] = { id:'2', fname:'dolor', lname: 'sit', uname: 'dsit', email: 'dsit@someemail.com', loca: 'CA', flags: 'afmnopt', active: '1' };
userss[ '3' ] = { id:'3', fname:'Test', lname: 'Testerson', uname: 'ttest', email: 'ttesterson@notreal.com', loca: 'TX', flags: 'afmnopt', active: '1' };
function usersx(x) {
    document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value = userss[x]["fname"];
    document.getElementsByName("lname")[0].value = userss[x]["lname"];
    document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value = userss[x]["email"];
    document.getElementsByName("user")[0].value = userss[x]["uname"];


    var rightChecks = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='right']");

    alert(userss[x]["flags"]);//this works
    for (x = 0 ; x < rightChecks.length ; x++){ //This is the point that it breaks
        //if(true){

            alert(userss[x]["flags"]);//this fails "Cannot read property flags of undefined"
            var a_link = new RegExp("/" + rightChecks[x].name[5] + "/");
            //alert(userss[x]["flags"]);
            document.getElementsByName(rightChecks[x].name)[0].checked = a_link.test(userss[x]["flags"]);
            //alert(rightChecks[x].name[5]);

        //}
    }
}
```

Very sorry if this ends up being a simple typo or something... I am just blind to it at this point.

edit: I was completely oblivious to the fact I was using X for my function and for my loop counter.  Thanks folks

Comment: Are you calling the function `usersx` anywhere in the script? Also, array index start from zero, so it is better to use `userss[ 0 ]` or to push elements to userss; using `userss.push(..)`. Also, you have a sparse array and `zeroth` element is missing and the reason for your error.

Comment: you're using the var 'x' both as an argument to the function and in the loop..change one of the two

Comment: Yep... TY very much oli I feel as stupid as i though i would...  And agalo I was calling it... I was just using bad var names.  Thank you both again

Comment: You don't have an index `0` in your array, which is where your variable `x` starts, that's why it breaks

Comment: Why are you using strings and not numbers? Just use push: var userss = []; userss.push({ /* your object */});

Comment: @epascarello It was simply because the ID used to be an 8 digit alpha numeric and I overlooked changing that when i updated the php side.  I do not use push because it could return id 1,6,9,12 now... and I do know that .push is more effective/efficient that just assigning it like this (the array is generated and by php)  Let me know if I am incorrect in doing this

Comment: If the array is sparse, than you probably should be using an object and loop over the keys.